# Pass arguments to decorators when calling decorated function

Tags: python

I'm at the very first experiences with the decorators, and I created a decorator class that filters the result of a target function, that returns by default a certain sequence:

```
class Filter(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None):
        self.id = id

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args):
            entity_ids = func(*args)
            result = {}
            for k, v in entity_ids.items():
                if self.id:
                    if '_' + str(self.id) in k:
                        result.update({k: v})
            return result
        return wrapper
```

I use the decorator in some other classes methods like this:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    @Filter(id=None)
    def get_ids(*args):
        return result_sequence
```

How can I define the arguments for the decorator when calling the class method:

```
>>>sc = SomeClass()
>>>sc.get_ids(*args)  # I want to pass the id kwarg for Filter here
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Martin's answer is exhaustive... or almost. If you want to be able to override the "id" argument when calling the decorated function you may do it using a keyword arg, ie:

```
class Filter(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None):
        self.id = id

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            id = kwargs.get("id", self.id)
            entity_ids = func(*args)
            result = {}
            for k, v in entity_ids.items():
                if id:
                    if '_' + str(id) in k:
                        result.update({k: v})
            return result
        return wrapper
```

BUT note that this implies that
 1. you WILL have to pass 'id' as a keyword argument if you want to overload the default
 2. you WONT be able to pass kargs to the decorated function that way (but you don't pass kargs anyway)

As a side note (and slightly OT here but...), your wrapper function's implementation could be improved somewhat:

```
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            id = kwargs.get("id", self.id)
            if not id:
               # no need to go further
               return {}

            id = "_%s" % id
            entity_ids = func(*args)
            result = dict(
                (k, v) for k, v in entity_ids.items()
                if id in k
                )
            return result
```

Answer (score 3):

You applied the `Filter` decorator in the class definition; it is *there* that you pass in the `id` argument:

```
@Filter(id=None)
```

If `id` should be something else, you need to pass that value in there.

The `Filter()` object is created in the `@Filter(id=None)` line, then called. You could also rewrite the code to read:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def get_ids(*args):
        return result_sequence
    get_ids = Filter(id=None)(get_ids)
```

as that is what Python does when it handles a decorator.

It is the *return value* of the `Filter.__call__()` method that replaces `get_ids`, you can no longer specify arguments to the `Filter()` object at that time. `SomeClass.get_ids()` is now the nested `wrapper()` function your decorator returned.

If you wanted to specify `id` when calling the decorated method, you'd need to alter the `wrapper()` signature to accept an (optional) extra `id` argument. Because you already support `*args`, your only option is to add a `**kwargs` catch-all argument to support optional keyword arguments:

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    id = kwargs.get('id', self.id)
    entity_ids = func(*args)
    result = {}
    for k, v in entity_ids.items():
        if id:
            if '_' + str(id) in k:
                result.update({k: v})
    return result
```

Here, instead of using `self.id` directly, a `id` keyword argument to the wrapper overrides the `id` value set on the decorator class:

```
sc.get_ids(*args, id='foo')
```

You may want to pass on any keyword arguments to the wrapped function as well; in that case, I'd use:

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    id = kwargs.pop('id', self.id)
    entity_ids = func(*args, **kwargs)
    result = {}
    for k, v in entity_ids.items():
        if id:
            if '_' + str(id) in k:
                result.update({k: v})
    return result
```

Here, the `id` keyword argument is *removed* before passing on the remaining keyword arguments to the wrapped function.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to change your wrapper:

```
class Filter(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None):
        self.id = id

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            id = kwargs.get('id', self.id)
            entity_ids = func(*args)
            result = {}
            for k, v in entity_ids.items():
                if self.id:
                    if '_' + str(self.id) in k:
                        result.update({k: v})
            return result
        return wrapper
```

This gives you the opportunity to give an alternative `id` value at the time of calling the wrapped method:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    @Filter(id=None)
    def get_ids(*args):
        return result_sequence
```

The `Filter` object's `__call__` method now returns a wrapper which has an additional `id` kwarg. Thus, you can override the `id` value given at class definition time:

```
sc = SomeClass()
sc.get_ids(*args, id='other')  # I want to pass the id kwarg for Filter here
```

Comment: def wrapper(*args, id=None): raises SyntaxError: invalid syntax